# How to show these two expressions are the same?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I think

[image]

Can be simplified to  $-x^2$

I tried `Reduce`, `FullSimplify`, `FunctionExpand`, and Mathematica is not able to confirm this.

Although for $x>8$ or so, the `res` expressions do not evaluate numerically to same as $-x^2$. This could be due to numerical issue in evaluating `res`.

```
ClearAll[x];
res=1/4 Hypergeometric0F1[4/3,x^3/9] (-8 x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/3},{2/3,4/3},x^3/9]+x^5 HypergeometricPFQ[{4/3},{2/3,7/3},x^3/9])+Hypergeometric0F1[2/3,x^3/9] (x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3},{4/3,5/3},x^3/9]-1/5 x^5 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/3},{4/3,8/3},x^3/9]);
f=-x^2;
Plot[{f,res},{x,-20,9},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue}]
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

```
Table[{f,res}/.x->n,{n,-2,2,.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[f - res, {x, -20, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]` seems to confirm your suspicion about the precision problem.

Comment: `Series[res - f, {x, 0, 200}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an indirect way to prove this. Applying `DifferentialRootReduce[]` to your `res` gives a tenth-order *linear* ODE:

```
Short[ode = First[Head[DifferentialRootReduce[res, x]]][y, x][[1]]]
   (-8741760 - 1918960 x^3 + 143800 x^6 - 2560 x^9) y[x] +
   (-7160448 x + 2599248 x^4 - 337056 x^7 + 6144 x^10) y'[x] +
   (11531328 x^2 - 1639768 x^5 + 265156 x^8 - 4864 x^11) y''[x] + <<6>> +
   (22272 - 36800 x^3 + 17144 x^6 - 704 x^9) Derivative[9][y][x] +
   (-11136 x + 7360 x^4 - 2143 x^7 + 64 x^10) Derivative[10][y][x] == 0
```

which means a solution of this ODE such as yours would be uniquely determined by ten initial conditions. Then, look at the series expansion, whose coefficients are exactly what you'd supply as initial conditions:

```
Series[res, {x, 0, 10}]
   -x^2 + O[x]^11
```

and you should be able to take it from there.